# Why is my button state inconsistant?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, inheritance

In my application I've 3 ways to browse local data:

- Simple file browser (`OpenFileControlUI`)
- Recently Opened Files (`RecentlyOpenedFilesUI`)
- File browser with filters (`FileFilterControlUI`)

Theses 3 controls inherits from a base class :

- `OpenFileControlUI` inherits from `OpenFileControl`;
- `RecentlyOpenedFilesUI` inherits from `RecentlyOpenedFiles`;
- `FileFilterControlUI` from `FileFilterControl`;

Theses 3 ones inherits from the same base : `DataBrowser`. This class has a toolStrip (`toolStrip1`) which has a button to load data (`loadToolStripButton`). I want to disable this button every time the reader of my application is busy, which I do like so:

```
protected DataBrowser()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    OpenFiles.Instance.ReaderStatus += ReaderStatus;
    //...
}
//...
protected void ReaderStatus(ReadStatusEventArgs e)
{
    loadToolStripButton.Enabled = (e.Status == ReadStatus.Ready);
}
```

The event is triggered normally and the button is enabled/disabled normally both in the `OpenFileControlUI` and the `FileFilterControlUI` but with the `RecentlyOpenedFilesUI` the button **is not disabled** whereas the debugger tells me it *is* disabled.

---

I've added a MessageBox to show the item state using :             `MessageBox.Show("The button is :" + (loadToolStripButton.Enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"));`

This is the result with the two working controls:

[image: working messagebox]

And this it the non working one (you can see that the button is not disabled as it should):

[image: non working one]

---

What bugs me is that this is:

- The only line in the whole project that change the Enable/Disable of this button;
- It doesn't matter if I build in Debug/Release;
- I've cleaned the project both with VS and deleting files manually;
- Adding a `Refresh` call doesn't help.

### It doesn't fix this bug.

Simple question : How can I fix this?

### Edit

Here's where I call it:

```
protected void ReaderStatus(ReadStatusEventArgs e)
{
    loadToolStripButton.Enabled = (e.Status == ReadStatus.Ready);
    MessageBox.Show("The button is :" + (loadToolStripButton.Enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"));
}
```

And here's the `DataBrowser.Designer.cs` file (I kept only part about this stupid button):

```
partial class DataBrowser
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    
    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(DataBrowser));
        this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
        this.loadToolStripButton = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
        this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // toolStrip1
        // 
        this.toolStrip1.CanOverflow = false;
        this.toolStrip1.GripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;
        this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.loadToolStripButton});
        this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
        this.toolStrip1.RenderMode = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderMode.System;
        this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(216, 25);
        this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
        // 
        // loadToolStripButton
        // 
        this.loadToolStripButton.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
        this.loadToolStripButton.Image = global::Sakura.UI.DataBrowsing.Properties.Resources.FormRunHS;
        this.loadToolStripButton.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
        this.loadToolStripButton.Name = "loadToolStripButton";
        this.loadToolStripButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 22);
        this.loadToolStripButton.Text = "Load";
        this.loadToolStripButton.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.loadToolStripButton.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage;
        this.loadToolStripButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.loadToolStripButton_Click);
        // 
        // DataBrowser
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
        this.Name = "DataBrowser";
        this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    protected System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip toolStrip1;
    protected System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton loadToolStripButton;

}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: you are registering to a singleton's even in the constructor. Are you unregistering from that event on disposal?

Comment: Otherwise, add a breakpoint or print on the ReaderStatus event to see if it is being called with a different status in the eventargs.

Comment: @Rotem no I don't, for the 3 controls. Should I ? Also, consider edit ;)

Comment: Could this be an update issue then? What happens if you add `loadToolStripButton.Refresh()` after setting `Enabled` to false? I think the question as it currently stands invites guesswork, I understand it's a complicated scenario but try to think of additional info that may be useful. If yopu say the problem is only with one of the controls, we need to know what the differences between it and the working ones are.

Comment: show where you are calling hte message box.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.enabled%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that `ToolStripItem.Enabled` property `Gets or sets a value indicating whether the parent control of the ToolStripItem is enabled.`

Comment: @Rotem there is no refresh for this object. But Adding a refresh to the toolstrip or the whole control doesn't change the result. Daniel, see edit

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it's a `ToolStripItem`.

Comment: @Rotem I could provide full code if needed

Comment: I think the key is figuring out what about this control is different from the other two.

Comment: maybe this is not the loadToolStripButton, change the text an check if it changes.

Comment: @RezaAghaei then how would it work in two cases but not in the last one?

Comment: I don't know how you find that button and assign it to loadToolStripButton variable.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've added (a part of) the designer file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I did a big cleaning:

1. Right click on Solution => <kbd>Clean Solution</kbd>;
2. Killed VS;
3. Deleted ALL STUPID FILES using `find . -iname "bin" -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r --` and `find . -iname "obj" -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r --` from my preferred console;
4. Shutdown the computer;
5. Took another coffee;
6. Restart Windows;
7. Restart VS;
8. Enjoyed the working code.

Side note: IF ANYONE FROM **THE VS DEV TEAM** READ THIS, PLEASE, MAKE <kbd>Clean Solution</kbd> **CLEAN THE SOLUTION FOR REAL**!

Comment: Probably `Closing VS + Deleting bin and obj` is enough, but sometimes `Another Coffee` makes a big difference ;)